# Learning Lisp. Can't seem to get a value from one function and use it within another

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, let

I'm trying to find the maximum number within a list, then do something with it:

```
(defun maxList (l)
    (if (= (length l) 1)
            (first l)
        (if (> (first l) (maxList (rest l)))
            (first l)
            (maxList (rest l))
        );if
    );if
);defun


(defun try-let (l)
    (let (a (maxList l))
    (print a)
    );let
);defun
```

However it prints null, yet maxList works. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `(let ((a maxList l)) ...)`

Comment: Please learn [how to indent Lisp code](http://dept-info.labri.u-bordeaux.fr/~idurand/enseignement/PFS/Common/Strandh-Tutorial/indentation.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a pair of parentheses:

```
(let ((a (maxList l)))
```

This is because `let` takes a list of bindings as in

```
(let ((a 1) (b 2) (c 'foo))
  expr)
```

so in this case you have to pass a one-element list containing the binding `(a (maxList l))`

Comment: Aha, ok, thank you! I am having a very hard time keeping up with the parentheses. Even though i have some working examples and using notepad ++ (good enough for now) I still get lost in them.

Comment: @Kalec Noticing missing parens is easy if you don't look for them, and instead look at the indentation. Believe it or not, in lisp they aren't as important as they are in other languages, they are used only do delimit expressions. Programmers look at the indentation, and they let their editor worry about it, and about matching parenthesis. That is why lispers will tell you to never leave parens on their own lines, it makes them much more important than they actually are. Check out http://www.cliki.net/Programming%20style

Comment: To add to this I have to say it was REALLY worth my while when I started learning lisp (feb 2012) to use an editor which supports you with your code, notepad++ (even though it is brilliant) will cause brain ache if you use it for lisp. I did this by learning emacs as I learnt lisp. Honestly being able to fire code from your source file to the repl with a simple key combo is a tranformative experience compared to how we develop in some languages. I recommend emacs24 and slime (and optionally paredit but this will annoy you as you get use to how it handles your code!). Good luck & happy lisping!

Answer (score 2):

```
(defun maxList (l)
  (if (= (length l) 1)
```

Calling `LENGTH` is not a good idea. It traverses the whole list.

```
      (first l)
    (if (> (first l) (maxList (rest l)))
        (first l)
      (maxList (rest l)))))
```

Above calls `MAXLIST` twice. Maybe here a `LET` is useful? How about the function `MAX`?

If you compile your function, a Common Lisp system will complain.

```
CL-USER 35 > (defun try-let (l)
               (let (a (maxList l))
                 (print a)))
TRY-LET

CL-USER 36 > (compile 'try-let)
;;;*** Warning in TRY-LET: MAXLIST is bound but not referenced
```

This shows that the Lisp compiler thinks `MAXLIST` is a variable. Something is wrong. Next look up the syntax of `LET`.

See [Special Operator LET, LET*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_let_l.htm)

```
let ({var | (var [init-form])}*) declaration* form* => result*
```

Which says that it is a list of variables or a list of (variable initform). So you can see that you have missed to make it a list. You have just written one binding.